# Run an application in a new Terminal window from a Java program

Tags: java, terminal, runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open a new prompt/terminal window from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738259/open-a-new-prompt-terminal-window-from-java)

Is it possible to open a terminal window and execute certain command from a java window?

I tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<command to execute>");
```

But it didn't work. No terminal window was ever opened.

(On Windows, Mac, etc...I need solutions for multiple operating systems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a solution for each OS:

- MacOs : `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal /path/to/the/executable");`
- Linux : `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("/usr/bin/xterm");`
- Windows (not sure ) :

  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe");
  p.waitFor();

Comment: (For the MacOSX), what if `/path/to/executable` is a command that takes arguments. How do I pass the arguments?