# How do I make a jarfile run in the command line from double clicking it (w/ out batch files)?

Tags: java, jar

I have a simple jarfile that contains the code for my Discord bot. When I double click it, it works perfectly. I can see the bot comes online and that the javaw.exe shows up in task manager. That's the only way I can see it's working and I can't see any errors or anything. It just runs in the background. How can I make it where when I double click it, it runs just like you ran it from a batch file (just like here: [Running a .jar file in a command prompt from double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543234/running-a-jar-file-in-a-command-prompt-from-double-click))? **I would like to do this without messing with batch files. I would just like one jarfile and that's it.** Is there some kind of code I can use in the jarfile to make it run in the command line automatically without having to enter the command or use a batch file? Maybe if I could use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start java -jar <jarfile>);` but somehow make it all work in one jarfile?

[image: Output]

Comment: to show the java output use `java.exe` instead of `javaw.exe` (the default) - this must be changed in the registry (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\Shell\Open\Command`) or using `ftype` (command line, e.g. `ftype jarfile="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" %*`; use `ftype jarfile` to see (and save) the original value!) [to avoid the console from closing, you must eventually change the command to `cmd /k start "JAVA" /b "%JAVA_HOME%\...` or similar {not sure, would have to test&try myself}]

Comment: oh, thanks a lot! I just changed javaw to java and it works