# Execute command in a separate cmd or terminal

Tags: java, linux, windows, terminal, cmd

It is possible to execute external commands in java at run time.

However, what I am looking for is to actually open cmd or terminal and show that executing external command on screen.

I tried to execute a jar console application as `java -jar jartool arguments`, it works both on Windows and Ubuntu. The only problem is that, this does not open cmd or terminal separately. it runs the command in background.

We can use either `ProcessBuilder` and the start process or simply `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`.

I need to forcefully open the cmd or terminal. Java is configured to show console on windows but still no luck.

Any idea why this is happening or what should I do to force it to open cmd or terminal independent of current cmd or terminal.

Comment: check for it, it should be what you're trying to do

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738259/open-a-new-prompt-terminal-window-from-java

Comment: @blurstream: Well just tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5738314/1584507) and worked in windows. Now will try to write separately to detect OS and execute cmd or terminal accordingly. :-)